# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

We are trying to build a Maven project on Jenkins and everytime we run into:

> [ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

We have tried the parameter:

```
-d64 -server -Xmx29G -Xms12G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremot
```

but nothing seems to be of any help.

Comment: Allocating several gigs of memory is unlikely to fix most any problem. This certainly sounds like a straight-up bug.

Comment: The error message indicated that this is caused by your own code which might might being cause running during a test or or during the compile time, but based on missing log output I can only speculate here...Needed to set 12G of stack size (-Xms) makes no sense just for compiling and running tests...

Comment: May be helpful: https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/requested-array-size-exceeds-vm-limit

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest using a heapdump + MAT.**

- add this flag to request a heapdump in case of memory issues:

  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
- use this flag to specify where the file should be created:

  -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/memory_issue
- use the following tool (MAT) to open and analyze the file:

  [Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)

Do not be scared of the functionality of MAT, even if half of the output does not make sense to you, the other half is usually enough to track down what is filling up your memory. Done well this investigation should take roughly an hour and then you will have a bug to fix.